# Netscan detected from host

Tags: dedicated-server, attacks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My server’s been hacked EMERGENCY](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)
>   [Portscan attacks from somewhere](https://serverfault.com/questions/329391/portscan-attacks-from-somewhere)

I am using Hetzner's dedicated servers. Today I have got a message:

```
We have received information that there was an attack from your server.

----- attachment -----

##########################################################################
#               Netscan detected from host      ?.?.?.?                  #
##########################################################################

time                protocol src_ip src_port          dest_ip dest_port
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Thu Dec  6 09:52:00 2012 TCP         ?.?.?.? 52204 =>     68.64.12.28 21   
Thu Dec  6 09:52:00 2012 TCP         ?.?.?.? 53276 =>     68.64.12.29 21   
Thu Dec  6 09:52:00 2012 TCP         ?.?.?.? 47344 =>     68.64.12.30 21   
...
```

How can I find out what is causing the problem and how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance,
Etam.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any network logging enabled? Does your host? Finding information after-the fact can be hard if you hadn't enabled verbose logging ahead of time.